# Preload image on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

How can I preload image only when event starts, i.e. `.scroll` or `.click` ?

What happens now is, image loads along with website, and I want to prevent this from happening.

Thanks.

Comment: _"How can I preload image only when event starts, i.e. .scroll or .click ?"_ Load image within event handler function ?

Comment: Yes. I don't want it to load when website loads.

Comment: Right.  Just add it in the event handler with some javascript or jquery instead of putting it in the DOM with HTML.  There are thousands of examples of how to do this already.

Comment: I should have stated up, I'm not really proficient with jQuery.. please post it as answer and if it works, I will mark it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.one()` , `.appendTo()`

```
$(element).one("click", function() {
    $("<img src=/path/to/img/>").appendTo(/* target element */)

})

 $(window).one("scroll", function() {
    $("<img src=/path/to/img/>").appendTo(/* target element */)
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
         var self = $(this);
         self.attr('data-src', self.attr('src'));
         self.removeAttr('src');
    });
    var loaded = false;
    function loadImages() {
         if (!loaded) {
             $('img').each(function() {
                 var self = $(this);
                 self.attr('src', self.data('src'));
             });
             loaded = true;
         }
    }
    $('button').click(loadImages);
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        loadImages();
        $(this).unbind('scroll');
    });
});
```

if the javascript is executed after images are loaded you can try to change img src to data-src in html file.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an image tag with the source in an data attribute:

```
<img data-src="your_image.jpg">
```

And then load it on an event:

```
$('body').on('click', function(){
  $('img[data-src]').each(function(i, img){
    $img = $(img);
    $img.attr('src', $img.data('src'));
    $img.removeAttr('data-src');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$(function(){
    $(document).one("scroll, click", function(){
       loadImages();
    })
})
```

Here loadImage is a function which will load your images on click/scroll event. "one" method will make sure that it only happens only once else you will end up loading images every time someone click or scroll.

Answer (score 0):

var src = 'location/file.jpg';

```
$(document).on('click', function(){
    $('target').append('<img src="' +src+ '" />');
});
```